# Almost surely of Randomvariable

Tags: probability

Let $\Omega  = [0,1]$ and $A = \{ \omega  \in \Omega :\omega  \ne \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\} $

Let $X(\omega ) = \frac{1}{\omega }$ and ${X_n}(\omega ) = \frac{n}{{|1 - n\omega |}}$ for $\omega  \in A,n \ge 2$

For $0 < \omega  < 1$ , $Xn(\omega ) = \frac{1}{\omega }$ and $n \to \infty $ thus $Xn \to X$ a.s  Since P(A)=1

My question is   For $0 < \omega  < 1$ it should be $0 < \omega  \le 1$ it True or false …Thank you.

Comment: Since $1$ is not an accumulation point for $A$, True.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

$$X_n(1)=\frac{n}{n-1}\to1=X(1)$$